# How do I link to divs being shown and hidden using jQuery fadein/fadeout from a separate page on my site?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, fadein, fadeout

I am creating a personal website that includes a portfolio page where I am featuring multiple galleries that can be toggled on and off using jQuery fadein/fadeout features. I also have links on my main index page that I would like to link to each individual div that contains a gallery.  Is there anyway to do this? I am fairly new at web design and jQuery.  The divs have a class assigned that positions them absolutely so that they overlap and each div has an id that is unique and is used in the jQuery code. Here is the code that I am using to display and hide the divs...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function() {
    $('#show_advertisement').click(function() {
        $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#show_logo').click(function() {
        $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_logos').fadeIn('slow');
    });
       $('#show_illustration').click(function() {
        $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeIn('slow');
    });
       $('#show_web').click(function() {
        $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
         $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#show_advertisement').trigger('click');

             });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you set up a jsFiddle with your HTML and JavaScript on it? I think it could help us help you.

Comment: put your markup also.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you link from the main-page index navigation with a hash to the div you want to show .. ala

your link: /gallery.html#show_illustration

Then on the gallery.html page, set up some code that then triggers the items you want to be clicked..ala

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.hash;
    $(url).trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: This actually didn't work, maybe I didn't use the code properly. I don't know much about Javascript, im in the process of learning PHP right now. Are there certain things I need to substitute into the code above for my own page or should it work by just copying and pasting the code above into my gallery page?